# C++でOpenSSLで非同期通信(ノンブロッキング)を行う方法

Tags: c++, c, http, openssl, 非同期

SSL_writeやSSL_readをノンブロッキングで処理したいです。(目的が達成できればBIOでもなんでも可)

スレッドではなく、select()のような関数を使って通知を受けたいと考えています。
具体的な方法を教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++だと勝手が違うかもしれませんが、Cなら普通に SSL_set_fd() に渡すファイルディスクリプタを、 ioctl() か fcntl() で ノンブロッキングに設定するだけです。

```
// fd = accept(soc, null, null);

int opt = 1;
ioctl(fd, FIONBIO, &opt);

// SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd);
// SSL_accept(ssl);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
基本的な質問をしてしまったようで申し訳ないです。
試してみます。